# Read committed isolation level and truncate table inside snowflake transaction

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Just a curious question in my mind and I thought of asking to Snowflake experts to clarify this question. We know that Snowflake default isolation level is read committed; I have one transaction let us A in which I am truncating data from Table T1 and Loading the Table T1 using transformed fresh data; at the same time I have another transaction say B is trying to read the data from Table T1 while getting this data truncated in transaction A; would I be able read the data from Table T1 in transaction B which it is still getting truncated in another transaction A.

My mind says yes; transaction B should be able to read it from Table T1 because transaction A still in progress and not yet committed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running these 2 scripts in two different tabs with app.snowflake.com:

Script 1:

```sql
set xxx = 'xxx1';
select $xxx;
-- xxx1

select *
from will_transact;

begin transaction;

delete from will_transact 
where a='a';
-- number of rows deleted = 1

commit;

select *
from will_transact;

begin transaction;

truncate table will_transact;

commit;
```

Script 2:

```sql
select $xxx;
-- Error: Session variable '$XXX' does not exist (line 1)

create or replace table will_transact as 
select 'a' a, 'b' b;

select * 
from will_transact;
-- 1 row

select * 
from will_transact;
-- 1 row

select * 
from will_transact;
-- 0 rows

create or replace table will_transact as 
select 'a' a, 'b' b;

select * 
from will_transact;

select * 
from will_transact;
-- 0 rows
```

If you run these 2 scripts in parallel, step by step, you will notice that:

- Each tab runs a separate session, the variables are not shared.
- Once you start a transaction and delete rows or truncate the table, the other session doesn't notice the changes until they are committed.

Comment: Very Nice Felipe ;very well designed scripts to demonstrate Read committed isolation level in Snowflake; thanks for your guidance